# Facebook returns #access_token

Tags: java, facebook, scribe

I am using Java Scribe + Spring MVC to access Facebook authentication API.

However, the URL with the access token I am getting back from Facebook is in this format:

```
/facebookCallback#access_token=[long chunk]&expires_in=5028
```

As you can see, the access_token is preceded by a #, which disallows me from obtaining the access_code as a normal parameter.

Is there any reason why Facebook is appending the # instead of a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it probably was caused by my school network. I tried the exact same code both in school and at home and got different results (school - error, home - correct).

The problem solved by itself the next day in school so I won't be able to find out exactly why. Thanks to those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = document.location.hash;
```

I think you mean Javascript , and not Java Scribe ?

Comment: Nope, meant this Scribe: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java (the OAuth library).

The problem solved by itself though, the # got replaced with a ? instead. Might have been my school network but I can't confirm it.

Comment: Victor can you write that as an answer and mark it as accepted? I'm trying to solve all `scribe` unanswered questions

Comment: Sorry Pablo, didn't see your comment until today. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably using the callback parameter which is designed for the JS library.  Make sure you are not sending an incorrect parameter for "type".